# Optimising a nested recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm able to create a nested recyclerview, where the child's recyclerview adapter is set in the `onBind` of the parent recyclerview. However there's a significant lag when the user scrolls the list, because `onBind` is called again and again to set data for the recycled view, which sets the adapter of the child recyclerview as well.

I've read a possible solution where recyclerview can share a common view pool [here](https://medium.com/@mgn524/optimizing-nested-recyclerview-a9b7830a4ba7) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6zex21/optimizing_nested_recyclerview/) . It solves the problem partially.

Also I've read nesting of recyclerview's is a bad practice.

How do I get rid of the lag when the user scrolls the list?

Comment: **`YES`** `nesting of recyclerview's is a bad practice.`

Comment: How do I approach this issue?

Comment: you can use expandable recyclerview base on your requirement

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath you can use  **[expandablerecyclerview](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/introducing-expandablerecyclerview)**

Comment: Yes, exapandable recyclerview solves this problem but I want a parent to have a single child item and that child item should have a horizontal list

Comment: @Nilu, the mentioned library has a major drawback - https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view/issues/27

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view